# Circuits in parallel of different voltages

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[image]

I've been having difficulty in understanding why the voltage across the resistor $3$ is $10V$. My main problem is understanding why the $12V$ resistor couldnt for example drop $1V$ on the first resistor and then drop $11V$ on $R_3$. Could anyone help explain this?

Answer (score 1):

The voltage on $R_3$ is 10 V *only* in the case where $R_1 = 0$, in this case there is no drop on $R_1$ and the resistor $R_3$ is in parallel with the source $V_1 = 10$ V, so that the voltage on $R_3$ is exactly $V_1$.

If $R_1 \not = 0$, you have to solve the circuit to find $I_3$. There are many ways of doing this, [Kirchhoff's circuit laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) are in general easy to understand and use. When you apply them you get

\begin{eqnarray}
I_1R_1 + 30I_3 &=& 10 \\
10I_2 + 30I_3 &=& 12 \\
I_1 + I_2 - I_3 &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}

Whose solution is

\begin{eqnarray}
I_1 &=& \frac{40}{40 R_1+300}, \\
I_2 &=& \frac{12 (R_1+30)}{40 R_1+300}-\frac{300}{40
   R_1+300}\\
I_3 &=& \frac{12 R_1}{40 R_1+300}+\frac{100}{40 R_1+300}
\end{eqnarray}

Note that the voltage accross $R_3$ is $I_3R_3$ and depends on the value of $R_1$

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I was very clear in my question. The first part of your answer is The situation in which my question was addressed. When R1 is 0. Do you follow?

Comment: @JakeRose Is then your question solved?

Comment: Maybe I'm being silly and this is quite a trivial problem but could you explain why the 12v supply is limited by the 10v supply?

Comment: @JakeRose It is limited by the resistor $R_2$

Comment: How do we know there must be 2v on R2?

Comment: Do you follow the first set of equations of my reply? It comes from the fact that the voltage drop on a closed loop must be zero

Comment: Yeah it does make a lot of sense with the equations. Do you have any intuitive understanding that you could possibly pass on to me?

Comment: @JakeRose If $R_1 = 0$ then the 10 V source will be directly connect to $R_3$, so the voltage between the two ends of this resistor must be 10 V. Similarly, the voltage between the two ends of the system formed by the resistor $R_2$ and the 12 V source must be 10 V. That means that the voltage has to drop 2 V at $R_2$

Comment: Why is it impossible to have two different voltages across a resistor if it is connected to two different supplies? Could the electrons passed through each different battery not drop of different amounts of energy?

Comment: @JakeRose Imagine that in your circuit $R_1 = R_2 = 0$, this would imply that the two supplies are in parallel, whether $R_3$ is there or not. So drop $R_3$ and try to think what would happen in this case

Comment: So if they are in parallel then you would have a net flow from the 12v to 10v as there is a potential difference there?

Comment: @JakeRose Please read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23943/what-would-happen-if-i-connect-two-different-dc-voltage-sources-in-parallel)

Comment: Im not sure I follow how that answers my question. It was mostly safety talk and computers

Comment: @JakeRose Well, it just shows that when you put two sources in parallel you basically have a short circuit, physically is the result of trying to push a current through a zero resistor. Mathematically is the result trying to solve 10 V = 12 V

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow?